# trying to make android studio Edit text display a message when the user enters the correct answer

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.kp0938972.brainbuster;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class riddleAnswers extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "Test message";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_riddle_answers);
        String answer1 = "";

        EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Riddle1Answer);
        answer1 = String.valueOf(edit);
        if(answer1.equalsIgnoreCase("Your Eyes"))
        {
            findViewById(R.id.WrongAnswer1).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.CorrectAnswer1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
        else
        {
            findViewById(R.id.CorrectAnswer1).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.WrongAnswer1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }
}
```

once i try and run this code it says null for the your eyes edit box and if i use the to string method it crashes my application. I would like to display a message on another page and it doesn't do that at all it just displays the wrong error message

Comment: You are not retrieving correctly your editText answer. Use edit.getText().toString()

Comment: Consider adding a "Submit Answer" button that, when clicked, will read in their answer and display correct/wrong. You're grabbing `edit` in `onCreate` without giving them a chance to answer. Also is there a reason you couldn't just make a toast to tell them they got it right/wrong?

Comment: no reason i just wanted it to go to a new page because i want to give them the change to enter all the answers them click the submit button to make them get to view the answers

Comment: what do i need to add first to give them a chance to answer first befor the information is grabbed in because i thought it would pull in what they entered in the line

Comment: and i have a button there it is linked in my other java file do i need to add that button to this java class and not my other one

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the text from the edit text.

```
edit.getText().toString();
```

Comment: when i do that it crashes my appli cation all together

Comment: 02-16 10:04:03.751 9145-9145/com.example.kp0938972.brainbuster E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.kp0938972.brainbuster, PID: 9145

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kp0938972.brainbuster/com.example.kp0938972.brainbuster.riddleAnswers}: java.lang.NullPointerExcept

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3155)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3263)

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1687)

Comment: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6897)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

Comment: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)

Comment: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at com.example.kp0938972.brainbuster.riddleAnswers.onCreate(riddleAnswers.java:18)

Comment: at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3108)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3263)

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1687)

Comment: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6897) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

Comment: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

Comment: @Kena Alys Pechacek Just add the log to your question next time there is no need to spam comments...

Comment: i dont know how to do that